# JSF exceptionhandler backing bean

Tags: jsf-2, exception

I have the code below to display the exception in the error page.

```
<h:outputText value="Exception message" /> 
<h:outputText value="#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}" />
```

I put a command button to pass the stacktrace in the backing bean in the following way:

```
<p:commandButton value="Error" action="#{reportError.reportError(requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message'])}"/>
```

I even tried to pass it using f:attribute or binding but did not succeeed. I am unable to retrieve it in the backing bean. Moreover, if instead of stacktrace I try to put any string hard coded it works but the stack trace doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: after rendering the page, `requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']` is not available anymore, so when using it in an action, it is 'empty'.

Comment: is there a way to get it in the backing bean then?